# Determine Radius of Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Trying to find the radius of convergence of the following series:

$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{(n!)^2} {(2n)!} {(z^n)}$

and

$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{(n!)} {(n)^n} {(z^n)}$

I tried using the root test for each and came up with (z) for the first problem and (z/n) for the second problem. Perhaps the ratio test is the way to go. I feel like my answers might be off. Could anyone offer some more insight? Thanks.

Comment: The radius of convergence should not involve the letter $z$. For example, the radius of convergence of $\sum \frac{z^n}{3^n}$ is $3$.  And definitely the letter $n$ should not appear.

Comment: $z$ means your are working in $\mathbb C$ or $z$ is as $x$ here?

Comment: The sequences are complex.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The Ratio Test works quite nicely for the first problem. Set up the ratio, do the obvious cancellations, and you will quickly find the limit.

For the second problem, the Ratio Test works. Set up the ratio, and manipulate a bit, looking for a chance to use the fact that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=e$.

The connection with the ratio arises from the fact that $1+\frac{1}{n}=\frac{n+1}{n}$.

Comment: Thank you, divided instead of multiplying. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The ratio test works for both series .

And the radius of convergence can't depend on $z$ or $n$.

$1/R=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} |{a_{n+1}\over a_n}|$

In the first series you get the ratio $1/4$ , so radius of convergence is $4$.

In the second one , use the fact that $\lim_{n\to \infty} (1+1/n)^n =e $ and get the ratio

limit $1/e$, so the radius of convergence is $e$.